# Match a not 8 character (digit/a-z/A-Z) long word through regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

This is the first question I post so sorry for anything I might screw up.

I've spent the past hour experimenting and searching for a way to replace "not 8 character (digit/a-z/A-Z) long word" with blank space (or in other words delete anything but those words) in Notepad++ through regular expressions.

I managed to bookmark the lines containing them but I'm stuck with the whole line that has that word, I just want those specific words. I'd appreciate any help, thanks a lot!

Edit2: A better way to phrase this is:
To remove anything that isn't: 8 character long that starts with an S and only contains digits and letters. In other words, remove anything that isn't S******* where *=digit,letter

Edit: I realized that's not enough to understand the situation so here's an example. I want to process this:

```
Here's your first code: S284JF2B
Here's your second code: SKE093JF
Here's your third code: S28fka30
```

And get this output:

```
S284JF2B
SD34EQ5M 
SASFKA30
```

The actual file has lots of other characters that are not just digits/letters and the codes I want on the output are always 8 character long (digits/Uppercase letters) always starting with an S.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What are the example lines? What is the output you need? What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. It's a backup file for sms messages (xml), This is a typical line:  
<sms protocol="0" address="4000" date="1466357701812" type="1" subject="null" body="SMS body, letters, digits, dots, exclamation mark " toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+000000000000" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1466358905000" readable_date="Jun 19, 2016 5:35:01 PM" contact_name="group1"   

For the output, the body has an 8 character (digits, letters) code, I want those codes to be the only thing on the xml file. The closest I think I got is M\d(\D)x7 (code starts with M)

Comment: Try `.*?\bbody="([^"]*)".*|.*` to replace with `$1`, and then remove empty lines.

Comment: your third code `S28fvka30` is 9 characters long and doesn't match the output at all

Comment: That made it a lot better! I still have other words in the same line as the 8 character code though. I added more info in the question, that might help I think :)

Comment: @le_m my bad, I wrote that manually. I fixed it :)

Comment: Try `.*?Here's your \S+ code: (\S{8}).*|.*` (or `.*?(?:Here's your \S+ code: (\S{8}))?.*`) and replace with `$1`.

Comment: Going to bed, your ? is still unclear.

Comment: Not at all. I was trying to apply the one you gave me to the document I have but I couldn't since the example I gave was supposed to be an indication to remove any string that isn't one that starts with an S, is 8 character long and contains digits and letters. In other words, remove anything that isn't S******* where *=digit,letter

Comment: @AmineErramy If you follow Wiktor's instructions (replace with "\1"), it should work

Comment: @le_m it did work with the example I gave but rather than applying in the example itself, it was just to indicate that I don't want anything else but the S******* code not particularly removing the "Here's your ....." it was just an example, the document I have has other strings that are not all a repetitive sentence. I'm sorry for all the trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two possible solutions. Both solutions require the string to be 8 characters long and begin with an `S`.

Given the this sample text:

```
the problem is it's not the words that do not contain any words that I don't want 
but actually any string that isn't a string that starts with an S and is 8 character long. 
Example: S294KS12 this is the type of string I want on the document. Contains 8 characters 
that are either digits or letters and starts with an S

SOMETIME
S294KS12
S1234567
S123456A
```

## Option 1

This solution only finds strings which are 8 characters long and start with an `S`.

```
\bS[A-Z0-9]{7}\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/lK0aO9/1

**Matches from Sample**

```
S294KS12
SOMETIME
S294KS12
S1234567
S123456A
```

**Explanation**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  S                        'S'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z0-9]{7}              any character of: 'A' to 'Z', '0' to '9'
                           (7 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Options 2

This solution does additional checking to ensure there is at least one additional letter and one number.

```
\bS(?=[A-Z]*[0-9])(?=[0-9]*[A-Z])[A-Z0-9]{7}\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/vH4lX2/3

**Matches from Sample**

```
S294KS12
S294KS12
S123456A
```

**Explanation**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  S                        'S'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]*                   any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]*                   any character of: '0' to '9' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z0-9]{7}              any character of: 'A' to 'Z', '0' to '9'
                           (7 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Putting all together

To replace everything else, then I'd incoprporate the regular expression into `( ... )\s?|.` Which will match everything, including the desired strings.

If you then use `$1` in the Replace with option in Notepad++, then you'll be left with just your desired strings.

I recommend using option 2 above, and inserting that into the expression so it looks like this:

```
(\bS(?=[A-Z]*[0-9])(?=[0-9]*[A-Z])[A-Z0-9]{7}\b)\s?|.
```

**Replace with:** `$1`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/gO7zV7/1

Comment: You're just the real deal. Thanks a lot for sticking with the question till the end. That was just what I wanted, sorry for the all the trouble you went through with the lack of information. Thanks again :)

Comment: @ro yo mi:  What kind of tool are you using to do these cool representations of Regular Expressions?

Answer (score 1):

**To match everything but the tokens from your example:**

`(^|\s)(?!S\w{7}\b)\S*`

For a live demo, see https://regex101.com/r/rW8mF0/4

**To match any non-8 character word:**

`\b\w{1,7}\b|\b\w{9,}\b`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

It matches words of length 1 - 7 **OR** words of length 9 and more.

For a live demo, see https://regex101.com/r/fX2sE5/1

Comment: Ha, after reading your solution, I'll bet that's exactly what they're looking for.

Comment: That actually detected the string I wanted once I edited it to \b\w{8}\b but it also detected lots of other 8 character words and I actually wanted the regular expression to match everything but the 8 character words thus the not 8 character long word. It's my fault though, didn't put enough information. I added the example to the question. Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: @AmineErramy I added a regex matching everything but your tokens (1 space + "S" + 7 characters + word boundary).

Comment: @le_m that almost worked! it actually did the job but left this before the code: < protocol="" ="" ="" ="" ="" =" : !    ' 
and this after the code:
 .  'utiliser  services! -------    " ="" ="" ="+" ="" ="-" ="" ="" =" ,  :: " ="" />

Is there any possible way to address any type of strings instead of just words? I think that's the problem here?

Comment: @AmineErramy If you post code, please add a ` before and after it

Comment: @le_m got it! sorry, just figuring out all of this.

Answer (score 1):

## Description

Lacking any proper examples, this will find substrings that are 8 characters long and not containing any letters. The substring must be bracketed by either whitespace or at the beginning or end of the string

```regex
(?<=\s|^)[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]{8}(?=\s|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/gS9uN7/1

**Sample text**

> I've spent the past hour experimenting and searching for a way to replace "not 8 character (digit/a-z/A-Z) **$#@!#$><** fd long word" with blank space (or in other words delete anything but those words) in Notepad++ through regular expressions.

**Sample Matches**

```
$#@!#$><
```

**After Replacement**

> I've spent the past hour experimenting and searching for a way to replace "not 8 character (digit/a-z/A-Z)  fd long word" with blank space (or in other words delete anything but those words) in Notepad++ through regular expressions.

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        after an optional start of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^a-zA-Z0-9\s]{8}           any character except: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                           'Z', '0' to '9', whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                           (8 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                             "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Clearly the more elaborate answer.

Comment: That really is a great answer. Even though it did not match what I wanted I enjoyed learning the explanation! the problem is it's not the words that do not contain any words that I don't want but actually any string that isn't a string that starts with an S and is 8 character long. Example: S294KS12 this is the type of string I want on the document. Contains 8 characters that are either digits or letters and starts with an S.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with following text to match your problem with the additional non-alphanumeric characters.

```
<protocol="toto" john="doe" Here's your first code: S284JF2B sign="+" />
<protocol="toto" john="doe" Here's your second code: SKE093JF sign="+" />
<protocol="toto" john="doe" 8char="s2345678" Here's your third code: S28fka30 sign="+" />
```

I used the following regular expression

`\b(\w{1,7}|(?=[^S])\w{8}|S(?![A-Za-z0-9]{8})\w{8}|\w{9,})\b|[^\w\r\n]`

I obtained only the codes when replacing with nothing and selected the option "**Match case**" in the replacement windows.

With a live demo here: https://regex101.com/r/wW3eB1

**Explanations**:

- `\b(...)\b`: word between boundaries
- `\w{1,7}`: word of 1 to 7 letters
- `(?=[^S])\w{8}`: word of 8 letters not starting by 'S'
- `S(?![A-Za-z0-9]{8})\w{8}`: word starting with a 'S', with 8 characters but containing something other than alpha-numeric (i.e. an underscore)
- `|\w{9,}`: word of 9 letters or more
- `[^\w\r\n]`: character that is neither a word or an EOL character

Comment: You got it one try, that's awesome! thanks a lot that totally did the job too. It's fun how you and Ro Yo Mi took different approaches (I guess?) and they both worked. I feel like I should give the answer acceptance to Ro Yo Mi though, he went through a lot to finally understand what I wanted and his answer is kind of more elaborate. I really appreciate your help though. My votes don't count yet but I also upped your answer. Thanks again, I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad it could help. By the way, in your original question you forgot to mention that you have special characters like double quotes, equal, etc. :)

Comment: Yes I realized that later I thought they're also considered as words or something, it was honestly kind of careless from my part. x)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the following regex `^.*(S[A-Z0-9]{7})(?!=[A-Z0-9]).*$`:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*(S[A-Z0-9]{7})(?!=[A-Z0-9]).*$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- DO NOT check `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               : begining of line
  .*            : any character 0 or more times
  (             : start group 1
    S[A-Z0-9]{7}: S followed by 7 alphanumeric characters
  )             : end group
  (?!=[A-Z0-9]) : negative lookahead to make sure there are no alphanum after
  .*            : any character 0 or more times
$               : end of line
```

Comment: That's awesome, it actually put the codes in a separate line which is better than missing them I guess but it didn't remove everything else on the document. Thanks a lot though, I appreciate it!